# Hugoniot Equations and Impact Pressure

Tags: pressure

I have a wave propagation question that regards two materials impacting each other. The question asks to find the impact pressure of the impact with a tungsten carbide flyer and a steel target.

I have calculated my two particle velocities from the left and right going Hugoniot equations however I always have trouble choosing which one is the correct one to use. I know if one is negative that the other is the obvious choice but for this specific problem I have two positive particle velocities. Up to this point I have simply done the calculations with both and decided to choose a reasonable pressure.

I was hoping there was maybe a check I could use to make sure I am using the correct particle velocity.

Thank you in advance!